# ggdag: Error in `dplyr::left_join()` relationship = "many-to-many"

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs, ggdag

This is my first time using the tool, but I do not understand why I do not manage to plot a graph. My original intention was to run a simple graph with many variables like the next one:

```
dagify(
  Y ~ Z1+X1+Z2+X2+U1+U2,
  X1 ~ Z1+U1,
  X2 ~ Z2+U2),
  exposure = c('X1','X2'),
  outcome = c('Y','Y')
) %>% ggdag()
```

This did not work, providing the next error:

```
    Error in `dplyr::left_join()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• relationship = "many-to-many"
Backtrace:
 1. ggdag::ggdag(simple_dag)
 4. ggdag:::if_not_tidy_daggity(.tdy_dag, ...)
 5. ggdag::tidy_dagitty(.dagitty, ...)
 6. ggdag:::ggdag_left_join(...)
 8. dplyr:::left_join.data.frame(..., multiple = "all", relationship = "many-to-many")
```

However, even the simplest of the graphs will provide me the same error; as an example

```
dagify(y ~ x) %>%
  ggdag()
```

Does someone understand the error message? The daggity objects, however seem to be fine. Here is an example of the last one:

```
print(dagify(y ~ x))
-------------------------------------------
dag {
x
y
x -> y
}
```